# Hbase or hdfs which will be better

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I have a use case in which we have large amount of data on which analytic is to be performed. The data will be continuously fetched and analytic to be performed at the run time. For this use case scenario what will be best to Use, Hbase+hive or HDFS+hive.
As much as I have read I have found that for run time changes its best to use Hbase. Needed some suggestion and advice. Please feel free to provide your inputs.

If you have any such use case in mind you can give example of it will be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is true that generically speaking HBase can yield better latency than Hive+MR.  However, much should also depend upon the particulars of your use case.  To give one example, do the analytics require performing relational joins between large sets of distinct data?  That use case is not quite as well a fit for HBase.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience so far, it often boils down to a choice between Hbase and Hive. Hbase fits well for use cases involving real time querying on data that is changing fast (chat messages), and Hive for use cases where analytics (often using SQL) needs to be performed over data that has aggregated over a long period of time (website analytics).